# adrci not purge trace files and alert logs

Tags: oracle, listener

I try to purge some files in oracle. I use adrci. I want to purge trace files in listener file. But it's not work. I don't know why.

```
[grid@orcl1 app]$ adrci

adrci> set homepath diag/tnslsnr/orcl1/listener
adrci> purge -age 360 -type alert
adrci> purge -age 60 -type trace
adrci> purge -age 1 -type trace
adrci> exit
```

Tracefile still full with 4.9 gb.

```
[root@orcl1 trace]# ls -alh
total 4.9G
drwxr-xr-x  2 grid oinstall 4.0K Nov  2 12:43 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 grid oinstall 4.0K May  7 14:48 ..
-rw-r-----  1 grid oinstall  43M Aug 28  2014 listener_backup_20140828.log.bz2
-rw-r-----  1 grid oinstall 4.8G Nov  2 12:43 listener.log
[root@orcl1 trace]# pwd
/u01/app/grid/diag/tnslsnr/orcl1/listener/trace
```

Comment: AFAIK alert log and listener.log can not be managed by adrci

Comment: so how can I ? with which tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ADRCI deletes the XML files, but not the plain text logs, which is a nuisance.

An easy but dirty solution would be overwriting the file with empty content, e.g:

```
$ cat /dev/null > listener.log
```

Deleting the file while the listener is running and logging is enabled may not lead to the expected result because of the file handling implementation on Linux/UNIX platforms.

Another solution is to temporarily disable logging, delete (or move or compress) the listener.log, then enabled logging again:

```
$ lsnrctl set log_status off
$ rm listener.log
$ lsnrctl set log_status on
```

Obviously, if you want, you can just stop the listener, take care of the listener log, then start the listener again.

Answer (score 0):

adrci purge will remove files according to your commands but not the contents of trace or log files.

Even though your listener.log has contents going back weeks/months/years it was modified today if the listener is up and accepting connections. The same for an alert log purge, if the db is online and the file was updated today, no purging will be performed.

If I come across a huge old alert or listener log, I'll copy them, compress the copy, then do a  >listener.log which will truncate the log but allow running processes to continue to update it.